# Overflow exception during sum of all the values of integer array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, aggregate, overflowexception

Hi I was solving a very basic problem on Hackerrank about determining Mini-Max Sum of all the values in an integer array. Basically given an array of 5 values like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the minimum sum will be 1+2+3+4 = 10 and maximum sum will be 2+3+4+5 = 14. Very simple question, but I am running into an issue with a certain large input values. Below are my solutions and their result.

```
//Input: 256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071625
//Output: 2063136757 2744467344
```

Below is using inbuilt **Sum()** method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = new int[5] {256741038,623958417,467905213,714532089,938071625};
    Array.Sort(arr);
    long arrSum = arr.Sum();  //System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'
    long minSum = arrSum - arr[arr.Length - 1];
    long maxSum = arrSum - arr[0];
    Console.WriteLine(minSum + " " + maxSum);
}
```

Below is using Aggregate extension method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    int[] arr = new int[5] {256741038,623958417,467905213,714532089,938071625};
    Array.Sort(arr);
    long arrSum = arr.Aggregate((total, next) => total + next); // arrSum = -1293758914
    long minSum = arrSum - arr[arr.Length - 1];
    long maxSum = arrSum - arr[0];
    Console.WriteLine(minSum + " " + maxSum);
}

Output: -2231830539 -1550499952
```

And if I use the regular foreach loop like below:

```
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr)
{
    Array.Sort(arr);
    long arrSum = 0;
    foreach (var value in arr)
    {
        arrSum += value;
    }
    long minSum = arrSum - arr[arr.Length - 1];
    long maxSum = arrSum - arr[0];
    Console.WriteLine(minSum + " " + maxSum);
}

The output is correct as expected i.e. 2063136757 2744467344
```

The OverflowException class description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=netcore-3.1) says "An arithmetic operation produces a result that is outside the range of the data type returned by the operation". But the `arrSum` value is within `long` range so I am not able to figure out the issue. So not sure if I am missing anything or using the functions incorrectly but not able to understand this behavior.

Any detail is appreciated.

Comment: _"the `arrSum` value is within `long` range"_ -- Your question is unclear. The `arrSum` variable has type `long`, so it cannot be anything other than within range. The exception is telling you that a calculation within the `Sum()` method resulted in a value that couldn't fit in a `long`. And indeed, the negative result from your use of `Aggregate()` suggests that you did exceed the maximum value, causing the storage value to wrap around to negative values. This can't be verified of course, because you didn't bother to provide a [mcve]. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Reason its failing is because the Sum() method is being executed on the `int` arrays. If you convert the numbers of the int array to long and then run the Sum operation on them, then you will get your result.

```
long arrSum = nums.Sum(x => (long)x);

// or, for readability
long arrSum = nums.Select(x => (long)x).Sum();
```

This will run the Sum operation only on `long`s. Way you are doing it, it sums up the integers until it is done with all of them and "then" saves it to your long.. while doing the addition, it fails because Int32 cant go too big.